# Banno Alert API Fails to Send Message Despite Returning AlertID

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

I have a process that utilizes the Banno Alert [API call](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/admin-api/api-reference/v0/alerts/details/#/Send%20Alerts/post_a_mobile_api_v0_institutions__institutionId__users__userId__alert_send_generic). In testing, it was working fine. All of a sudden, the test messages stopped coming through despite the API returning a successful code of 200 with an associated AlertID.

Looking in my Banno test app as well as the Admin backend site, there is no message sent to my account and I did not receive a push notification. I tried sending a test message to another user who was successfully getting the message and push notification earlier. He did not receive a push notification but the message does show up on his account.

I've tried changing the text of the title and body in case you can't send the same thing twice. I also tried waiting a day in case there was a system issue causing this problem but I am encountering the same issue the next day. Is there something that m

Comment: It may have been a temporary blip somewhere in the system (e.g. it's possible that the push notification provider had an issue, or similar). Do you have a `x-request-id` from the response header and rough day/time for the behavior?

Comment: Hi Jaime, I ran the process at 10:56AM PST today (2023/02/02) and encountered the same issue of no alert, no push notification. I am unfamiliar with the response header as the only thing I get out of the response is the AlertID which was formatted like so: {"alertId":"81a6c7c6-952f-47be-952d-2c2cf6bbd6f2"}. The server returned the following in the logs: Response code received from Http Server, Code 200.

Comment: It'll be challenging to find that specific request given the response body. I'm not sure what you're using to try this out, but hopefully there are options for your command line terminal or options for the code you're using to print out the response headers. That's where you'll find the `x-request-id`.

Comment: @Jaime I believe this should be what you are looking for from 2/6/2023 10:19AM CST: 51426cce7858222d03a9ff070c48c62d

Comment: can you re-verify that the *devices* you are using have push notifications enabled (in the operating system) for the Banno app for your institution? Also can you re-verify that the *user*, with `userId` is the same as you are testing? It appears as though you may have _two_ similar, but _separate_, users which have the same name. (Which may be a source of confusion.)

Comment: It appears as though one of the two users (with the same name) has mobile devices and push registration, while the other user (with the same name) does not have any.

Comment: @jaime Thank you for the advice. There is a disconnect between my accounts within our test system that was resulting in the issue. The process is working for the accounts that do not have a disconnect so I would say this issue is resolved.